# Can't install Updates by Software Updater

Tags: update-manager

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 some days ago. Now I am trying to update software using Software Updater, but it stops at:

```
Reading Database
```

I ran some commands on reading some websites, this is what I get as errors, please help:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

$ ps -ef | grep apt
root      2206     1  0 17:56 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
root      2347  2206  2 17:56 pts/12   00:00:16 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
root      2583  2347  0 17:57 pts/22   00:00:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 52 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
sp        2948  2899  0 18:06 pts/24   00:00:00 grep --color=auto apt
```

Comment: I have had a couple times already where the lock is on there and I don't know why. A restart fixed it. Silly suggestion but...

Comment: Tried Restart many times & also tried several commands I got off the net to forcefully remove the lock. No luck so far.

Comment: @Aditya Tried various commands on the webpage whose link you have included above. Still get this message: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Can someone please give me the specific command after identifying the offending apt?: sp@sp:~$ ps -ef | grep apt
root      2206     1  0 17:56 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
root      2347  2206  2 17:56 pts/12   00:00:16 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
root      2583  2347  0 17:57 pts/22   00:00:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 52 --unpack --auto-deconfigure /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.1_i386.deb
sp        2948  2899  0 18:06 pts/24   00:00:00 grep --color=auto apt

Comment: @IndianArt Reboot your system and then run that `ps` command to see the `apt` process which you need to kill.

Comment: @Aditya As soon as I rebooted I typed this command in the terminal, without starting any other program. Its output was:

sp@sp:~$ ps -ef | grep apt
sp        2419  2370  0 18:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apt
Please could you give me the exact command because i am not an expert with the Terminal. Thanks.

Comment: @IndianArt Oli gave you a good answer.. Right now, none of the apt/dpkg process is running. You so, may remove the lock following [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/102084/114818) and re-run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: So just remove the stray lock and all is well...hopefully

Comment: @RhZ I am unable to remove this stray lock with all the different commands I got on the net. The Software Updater repeatedly stops at "Running post-installation trigger dpkg-exec" & the last line of the report is "(Reading Database..."

Comment: Wow I really don't know what to say, could you maybe reinstall? A pain in the butt I know, but it might be the path or least resistance...

Comment: @Rhz This is possible because I have been trying 'stunts' by installing all kinds of stuff over several months. My impatience might have broken something in the last installation of a tool called ‘Folder Color’. its been 3 releases that I have been upgrading online (not fresh install), so its high time I do a fresh install. Thanks for all the help tho.  :)

Comment: @IndianArt ok cool, yeah especially in my early days there were lots of reinstalls when things got screwed up. I recommend making a partition for file storage, I always divide my hard drive, so that if I have to reinstall I can save all files. Good luck!